# Background color on only text

Tags: html, css

The text in `h3` is dynamic and the width of it's parent is static and I want to manage it in the following way:

[image: Output I need]

```
.sh-link{
    width:100%;
    max-width: 200px;
   }

.sh-link h3{
    text-align: right;
    background: orange;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    display: inline;
}

    <div class="container">            
      <div class="sh-link">
        <h3>See details on dealer website</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Can any one help me out?

Comment: where is your code ? what have you tried ?

Comment: Show your code not images

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
.container {
  width: 300px;
  display: flex;
}

.left p,
.right p {
  width: 100%;
  background: orange;
  color: white;
  display: inline;
}

.left {
  text-align: left;
}

.right {
  text-align: right;
}

.separator {
  background: white;
  width: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left"><p>See details on dealer website</p></div>
  <div class="separator"></div>
  <div class="right"><p>See details on dealer website</p></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You should use `:after` pseudo to archive this

```css
h1 {
  float: left;
  width: 300px;
  font-size: 0;
}

h1:after {
  content: attr(data-text);
  font-size: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  background-color: orange;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<h1 data-text="See details on dealer website">See details on dealer website</h1>
```

If you want to align right text, only need to add `text-align: right` to `h1` selector.